# AWS EC2 Status Check says "Instance reachability check failed " with kernel panic

Tags: amazon-ec2, kernel

I went to reboot my Centos 7 instance and then did a start/stop and now I get a status check error stating the instance is unreachable.
I created a snapshot and image of the volume and recreated a new instance with an extra 4GB of space and I still have the same issue.

I also detached and attached the volume again but it still doesn't work. I cant access website now as a result.

Instance says its running yet the Status Check says its unreachable. I also can't SSH into the server.
Can anyone advise what the issue may be?

Log:

```
Error: Instance reachability check failed at July 19...
Error log: kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (0,0)
Instance ID: i-069eecb6048260c51
Log: https://postimg.cc/image/9wa1is2ct/
```

Comment: Can you restore from the last snapshot, then mount the current volume as a data volume and copy updates? Things still fail in the cloud, you still need backups.

Answer (score 1):

This is telling you that it's not finding the boot loader. Sounds like a corrupt file system. You may be able to recover by creating a completely new instance and mounting your volume on it.

Comment: Thanks ....ya I tried mounting volume onto new instance but same kernel panic issue persists. I've no snapshot. Luckily It's not a big issue but would like to fix all the same

Comment: Don't mount it as the root volume, sorry, the idea was to see what's wrong, not fix it - you should be able to mount it on /mnt or whatever to at least see what's in the file system.